# Can #Develop debug a 64-bit process

Tags: debugging, sharpdevelop

I am trying to use #Develop to debug a 64-bit process. This does not seem to be supported, tho the newest information I found on this topic is from 2011-2012. E.g. http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/p/12569/34250.aspx

It that still the case, that it is simply not possible to attach to a 64-bit process?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. After reading [this](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/issues/724), I simply downloaded the sourcecode and compiled it into a 64-bit process. Works like a charm, and I can debug 64-bit applications.